# DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting, amazon-route53

My website had been running smoothly with no problems but I had one particular page, the booking page, that was being shown as HTTP. And I wanted to secure that page by redirecting HTTP to HTTPS using AWS > Cloudfront and Certificate Manager.

But I noticed yesterday that my website was not loading on any web browsers. My site is effectively down.

I have scoured the internet for answers and most of the answers discuss, clearing the web browser cache, which I've done. This does not seem to fix my issue. I have since deleted CloudFront configuration and certificate manager in an attempt to just get the site back live. However, it is still not loading properly.

It has been over 24 hours for DNS to propagate.

- My domain is registered with AWS Route53
- Hosted with Bluehost
- The website is built with WordPress.
- In AWS Route53, I have A, MX, NS, SOA, TXT records.

Here is the error message through the web browser:

> This site can’t be reached
> Check if there is a typo in [www.myprohousekeeper.com](http://www.myprohousekeeper.com).
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Any tips or suggestions of things to check would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When I go to `myprohousekeeper.com`, it seems to redirect to `www.myprohousekeeper.com`, which then fails to resolve. I can successfully `ping myprohousekeeper.com`, which resolves to `50.87.192.155`. However, I cannot resolve the DNS name `www.myprohousekeeper.com`. I suggest you check your DNS configuration and see whether an entry exists for `www.`

Comment: Thanks this helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: I recommend using https://dnschecker.org/ to verify whether the DNS updates have propagated or not